# Angular ngOnInit force firing when component reload

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm using Angular2 and gonna load content on **`Settings page`** for every account.

URL structure below

```
URL1 http://example.com/account/NICKNAME_1/settings
URL2 http://example.com/account/NICKNAME_1/orders

URL3 http://example.com/account/NICKNAME_2/settings
URL4 http://example.com/account/NICKNAME_2/orders
```

If I'm going from URL1 to URL3 (or URL3 to URL1) then `ngOnInit` doesnt fire for `settings component`.
This is expected behavior because Angular trying not to reload component.

Subscribing on changing params in `settings component` doesnt solve the issue because there are no parameters.

How can I detect changing Account name inside of `Settings component`?

Comment: Of course there's a param, the name. It's just on `route.parent` unless you configured it to pass params down. Also, if you really do want to force the component to reinitialize, you can write your own component reuse strategy. But there's no good reason to do that here.

Comment: Great. Subscription on route.parent.params helps.

Thanks!

Comment: I've added it as an answer so you can accept it (and upvote, if you want) so that the question is marked as solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Subscribing on changing params in settings component doesnt solve the issue because there are no parameters.

You'll find the account name as a param on the route parent:

```
route.parent.params.subscribe(...)
```